# compare 2 rows in a table

Tags: mysql, sql, hive

I have MySQL table like below

```
accountNum  date  status  action qty time
----------  ----  ------  ------ --- ----
1234        2017   filled  B      10  11:20
1234        2017   filled  S      10  11:20
2345        2017   filled  B      20  12:00
2345        2017   filled  B      10  12:00
4444        2017   filled  B       5  01:00
4444        2017   filled  S       5  02:00
```

Here I want to compare 2 rows with action "B" and then action "S". If found 2 rows with first B and then S on those records I have to check accountNum,date,time,status is same.

So based on above test data I should get only first 2 rows

```
accountNum  date  status  action qty time
----------  ----  ------  ------ --- ----
1234        2017   filled  B      10  11:20
1234        2017   filled  S      10   11:20
```

For this what type of query I should write?

Comment: How's hadoop related to the problem? And are you using MySQL or sqlite3?

Comment: Do the records always come in pairs of the same account number?

Comment: Just to clarify: SQL? It doesn’t matter which? Secondly, what do you mean by “first”? I know that sounds like a silly question, but in SQL row order is not defined unless you include an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Show us more data which highlights the edge cases which may occur.  If you can't do this then you are not ready to ask a question here IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a preliminary count on your key

```
select  accountNum, date, status, time
from    yourTable
where   action in ('B', 'S')
group by accountNum, date, status, time
having  count(distinct action) = 2
```

Then you can join the above with the initial table to filter only the rows you want

```
select  t1.*
from    yourTable t1
join    (
            select  accountNum, date, status, time
            from    yourTable
            where   action in ('B', 'S')
            group by accountNum, date, status, time
            having  count(distinct action) = 2
        ) t2
on      t1.accountNum = t2.accountNum and
        t1.date = t2.date and
        t1.status = t2.status and
        t1.time = t2.time
```

**Edit**

I'm not an expert with Hive, but if `distinct` and `having` are not allowed in subqueries, you can probably write your query like this

```
select  t1.*
from    yourTable t1
join    (
            select  accountNum, date, status, time, count(action) as cnt
            from    yourTable
            where   action in ('B', 'S')
            group by accountNum, date, status, time
        ) t2
on      t1.accountNum = t2.accountNum and
        t1.date = t2.date and
        t1.status = t2.status and
        t1.time = t2.time
where   t2.cnt = 2
```

You can get rid of the `distinct` altogether if the same `accountNum / date / time / status` combination cannot have multiple instances of the same action.

The `having` clause can be moved in the outside query as a `where` condition.

Comment: Yes , that'll work - but seems like overkill for such a trivial problem

Comment: @Strawberry you're probably right, but I kept it quite generic because the question leaves some degree of doubt on the possible values of the columns

Comment: @Strawberry - and what will be  easiest way for doing this in mysql ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze a simple join will suffice

Comment: Hi thanks it works in mysql but I want this to be in HIVE tables .. HIVE doesnot support HAVING and DISTINCT .is there anyway to solve this in HIVE query in easy way .. ?

Comment: Hi its giving only action with S.. I want a paired rows with B and S .. B means buy and s means sell .. I want to check buy and sell on same day !